# Java (Android) - With PHP a IsLoggedIn Method

Tags: android

I will make a IsLoggedIn Function with PHP (because i check again the name and password in db), but i get a NetworkOnMainThreadException in my logcat.
What is wrong?

```
public boolean LoggedIn() {
    try {
        int success;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CHECK_URL, "POST", params);
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if(success == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the exception says, you can't run network operations on the UI thread on Android. You will need to run them on a separate thread so your application doesn't freeze while you're doing stuff on the network. The most common approach for this is an AsyncTask.

Comment: i have tryed the asynctask but its not worked.
can you give me a example?

Comment: The example in Google's docs seems pretty simple to me. Which part are you having trouble with? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Essentially, you do your network stuff in doInBackground(), and then you put it in your UI (assuming you need to) in onPostExecute().

Comment: i have this in my userfactory:
pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/9XpQBrF4

and in my login:
http://pastebin.com/7NYkeLAf

but in login.java i cant access to isloggedin